# Wait for result from multiple callbacks/lambdas in Kotlin

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, okhttp

I'm making an app in Kotlin. Up until this point, my networking calls didn't have to be used together. I am now in a spot where I need to make two concurrent networking calls, pause until I receive both of their responses, and then continue execution. I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

```
    //first networking call, get resourceOne
    var resourceOne : String?
    Server.asyncRequest(RequestBuilder(endpoints.second, ids, params)) { resource: String?, error: ServiceError? ->
        resourceOne = resource
    }

    //second networking call, get resourceTwo
    var resourceTwo : String?
    Server.asyncRequest(RequestBuilder(endpoints.third, ids, params)) { resource: String?, error: ServiceError? ->
        resourceTwo = resource
    }

    //do something here wiith resourceOne and resourceTwo
```

The function header for my asyncRequest function is:

```
fun asyncRequest(requestBuilder: RequestBuilder, completion: (resource: String?, error: ServiceError?) -> Unit) {
```

It just wraps around an okhttp request and does some extra processing/parsing. Normally I would just take the result (resource) and process it inside of the completion lambda, but since I need both values, I can't do that here. I've tried doing something similar to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#concurrent-using-async) but my asyncRequest function does not have a return type, so I have no way of doing the async/await the way the link does.

Comment: You can use Kotlin Coroutines for this purpose.

Comment: @Anggrayudi I have read the documentation regarding coroutines, as mentioned in my post, but do not understand how I am supposed to apply them in this specific case. The only examples I've found are where the coroutines have a return type, not a callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with **Coroutines** along with **Flow** with something like this:

Turn **callbacks** into **suspendable functions** with a `suspendCancellableCoroutine {...}` block:

```
suspend fun <T> request(requestBuilder: RequestBuilder): T = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    Server.asyncRequest(requestBuilder) { resource: T, error: ServiceError? ->
        if(error != null)
            cont.resumeWithException(error) // Makes the Flow throw an exception
        else
            cont.resume(resource) // Makes the Flow emit a correct result
    }
}
```

Create a **Flow** to make the **first request**:

```
val resourceOneFlow = flow {
    emit(request<String>(RequestBuilder(endpoints.second, ids, params)))
}
```

Create a **Flow** to make the **second request**:

```
val resourceTwoFlow = flow {
    emit(request<String>(RequestBuilder(endpoints.third, ids, params)))
}
```

**Combine** both **Flows** with the `zip` operator:

```
val requestsResultFlow = resourceOneFlow.zip(resourceTwoFlow) { resourceOne, resourceTwo ->
    // Build whatever you need with resourceOne and resourceTwo here and let it flow
    "$resourceOne $resourceTwo".length // Here I concatenate both strings and return its length
}
```

Activate/Start the **Flow** with the `collect` operator and consume its **result**:

```
requestsResultFlow.collect { length ->
    // Consume the result here
    println("$length") // Here I print the number received
}
```

You have the **Flow** documentation [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html).