# Pause one operation until another finishes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two functions A and B and I don't have any control over them that which function will execute when.
Now i want the code inside B to run only after A has finished its execution, till then it should wait.

To achieve this: I used Coroutines and called the complete code inside A by using:

```
private lateinit var waitUntilFinished : Deferred<Boolean?> 
fun A(){    
    waitUntilFinished = lifecycleScope.async{ //todo}
}

fun B(){
     lifecycleScope.launch {
         waitUntilFinished.await()
}}
```

Now the problem is I am getting "lateinit property has not been initialized error" for "waitUntilFinished.await()" because B() is running after A(). Now how can i make it work?

The issue is similar as explained in this SO thread: [android camera2 api - onImageAvailable is not invoked after session.capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585765/android-camera2-api-onimageavailable-is-not-invoked-after-session-capture)

Comment: `B` must have been called before `A`, can you sow how is it invoked?

Answer (score 0):

If `B()` is called before `A()`, the lateinit property is not initialized and the error is thrown. Initialize `waitUntilFinished` in `B()` if it's not initialized and call `A()`.

Something like this:

```
    private lateinit var waitUntilFinished : Deferred<Boolean?>
    fun A(){
        waitUntilFinished = lifecycleScope.async{
            return@async true
        }
    }
    
    fun B(){
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            if(!::waitUntilFinished.isInitialized) {
                waitUntilFinished = lifecycleScope.async {
                    A()
                    return@async false
                }
            }
            waitUntilFinished.await()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can't call A() from B() as A is a : ImageAvailableListener which gets called automatically when we capture image. In some devices it gets called after onCaptureCompleted() which is B() here and in some devices it gets called prior to onCaptureCompleted()

Comment: i have also added one link in question which is similar to my problem.

Comment: Basically you need to wait for two callbacks to finish and then you can continue your code execution, right? This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556171/8835675